# Lognormal truncated distribution with R, random values

Tags: r

I need to generate random values that represent times (in seconds) that follow a lognormal distribution with:

```
Min: 120 seconds
Max: 1260 seconds
Mean: 356 seconds
SD: 98 seconds
```

I am generating 100 random numbers:

```
library(EnvStats)
sample1 <- rlnormTrunc(100,356,98,120,1260)
```

and when I calculate the mean, it is not `356`, but higher, about `490` seconds.  Why?

I don't understand what I am doing wrong as I though I was going to get the same mean.

Does anyone has an answer for this?

Comment: Wouldn't you get a different mean each time you run it? take for instance mean(rnorm(100,mean=356,sd=10)). The mean of the distribution of the mean is however 356 that would be normally distributed according to the CLT, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

If I use mean(rnorm(100,mean=356,sd=98)) I get mean=356 what is what I want... I get almost the same value everytime I run that line. Why then I dont get the same value when I run mean(rlnormTrunc(1000,356,98,120,1260))

Comment: You need to add a library call for whatever package has that function and you need to review the help page to determine what parameters are being set with that call. If you have parameters for a lognormal distribution with a particular mean and you truncate it on the LHS then you would expect the sampled values to have a higher mean.

Comment: @AndresT' yes its random but i dont think thats what it is. Try `out <- replicate(100, mean(rlnormTrunc(100, 356, 98, 120, 1260))) ;
hist(out)`.  From [the help](http://www.inside-r.org/node/219065)  the mean is specified as the mean of the non-truncated distribution ... (so taking a punt)  as the truncation is less in the lower side, the mean of the random vector you generate will increase above what you specify

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! Is there a way to get the same mean as my original dataset (356 seconds) knowing that the truncation will increase that mean? Thanks!

Comment: @user20650 any idea? :)

Comment: nope., sorry. you need some stats advice. Have a search to see how the mean of a truncated lognormal distribution is defined ... I imagine it will be some transform of the underlying (non-truncted) lognormal, that accounts for the upper and lower bounds. You can then back calculate???

Comment: Thanks! I will try to search.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you compare different distributions, so when you create random numbers out of these distributions, their mean is different.
If we take as an example the normal distribution then

```
set.seed(111) 
sample1 <- rnorm(n=10000,mean=356,sd=98)
mean(sample1) #355.7724
```

the mean would indeed almost 356. But if we took the truncated Normal Distribution then

```
set.seed(111)
sample2<-rnormTrunc(n=100000,mean=356,sd=98,min=120 ,max=1260)
mean(sample2) #357.9636
```

the mean would be  slightly different, around 358 **but not 356**. The reason why the difference is so small is because, as seen in the histogram

```
hist(rnorm(n=10000,mean=356,sd=98),breaks=100,xlim=c(0,1300))
abline(v=120,col="red")
abline(v=1260,col="red")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k3D5.jpg)

by truncating,  you take out very infrequent values ( smaller than 120 and bigger than 1260).

LogNormal is a fat-tailed distribution, skewed to the right. This means that it includes far more infrequent values than the normal distribution, far beyond 1260. If you truncate the distribution between 120 and 1260

```
hist(rlnormTrunc(10000,meanlog=356,sdlog=98,min=120,max=1260),breaks=100)
```

you get

```
set.seed(111)
mean(rlnormTrunc(10000,meanlog=356,sdlog=98,min=120,max=1260))  #493.3903
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OudV.jpg)

In each of the examples above you calculate the mean for a random set of values of different ranges because of different distributions, that's why you end up with different mean values.